# Not able to access value of a jenkins groovy variable in shell script for loop

Tags: jenkins, shell-scripting

When i am passing value of a variable declared in jenkins Groovy script its value is not retained in "for" loop which runs on a remote server. Strange thing is i am able to access the same value on remote server outside the for loop.

Here is the sample code i am trying to use

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def config
def COMMANDS_TO_CHECK='curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc'
pipeline {

    agent {
        label "master"
    }

    stages {
            stage ('Validation of commands') {         
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """
                    #!/bin/bash
                    /usr/bin/sshpass -p passwrd ssh user@host << EOF
                    hostname

                      echo $COMMANDS_TO_CHECK ---> This is printed
                          for CURRENT_COMMAND in \$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK
                        do
                        echo ${CURRENT_COMMAND}  ---> Why This is not printed?
                        echo \${CURRENT_COMMAND} ----> Why This is not printed?
                        done
                        hostname
EOF
                        exit

"""

}
}
}
}
}
```

OutPut

```
[workspace@3] Running shell script
+ /usr/bin/sshpass -p passwrd ssh user@host
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
illinsduck01
curl grep hello awk tr mkdir bc
illinsduck01
+ exit
```

Comment: Why do you use a backslash: `for CURRENT_COMMAND in \$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK` ??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the backslash in front of `$COMMANDS_TO_CHECK`, so:

```
for CURRENT_COMMAND in $COMMANDS_TO_CHECK
```

This is because `COMMANDS_TO_CHECK` is a Groovy variable and will be interpreted by Groovy inside of double-quoted strings.

Also use a backslash in front of `$CURRENT_COMMAND`, so:

```
echo \${CURRENT_COMMAND}
```

This is because `CURRENT_COMMAND` is a shell variable, not a Groovy variable, so you do not want it to be interpreted by Groovy inside of double-quoted strings.

Comment: Even after removing backslash its not working. The shell code is running on a remote server after sshpass ... i tried everything don't know where the issue is